# react error All imports in import declaration are unused

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, tailwind-css

please can I get some help with this code I do not understand why it is not using the imported elements. The error I am getting is All imports in import declaration are unused. I understand what this error implies I just don't know why the import is not working because I have used the elements as you can see below.

```
import { hero, volunteer, aims, meetings, footer } from "./sections";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <main className="relative">
      {/* <nav /> */}
      <section className="xl:padding-1 wide:padding-r padding-d">
        <hero />
      </section>
      <section className="padding">
        <volunteer />
      </section>
      <section className="padding">
        <aims />
      </section>
      <section className="padding">
        <meetings />
      </section>
      <section className="bg-black padding-x padding-t pb-8">
        <footer />
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I have no errors with the export below.

````
import aims from "./aims";
import footer from "./footer";
import hero from "./hero";
import meetings from "./meetings";
import volunteer from "./volunteer";

export { aims, footer, hero, meetings, volunteer };```


I have tried to import each element individually and also have tried to import directly to the app file with no success on both accounts.
````